# How to add blocking handlers with Netty 5.0?

Tags: http, netty, scheduling, blocking

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [new Netty threading model](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy-in-5.0) to add blocking handlers to a Netty 5.0 pipeline. Previously, this task was performed with ExecutionHandler and OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, but these do not exist in Netty 5.0. If I schedule my own threads to run, when the blocking task finishes running, the channel has already been closed.

What is the right way to schedule blocking tasks in Netty 5.0? I am writing an HTTP server that needs to hit a database before returning a result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a EventExecutorGroup when adding your ChannelHandler to the ChannelPipeline.

See http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#wiki-h3-35